How to setup R53 for API gateway
I am using SAM template to create a lambda function (AWS::Serverless::Function) with API gateway.
This API gateway has many routes in it. But I don't like the weird name for the API URL (zz56tgxe.amazon...).
If I have to have a user defined URL for my API what should I have in my template?
I already have a R53 hosting zone in my AWS account (something like int.coredev.xxx.com)
My questions are:

Should I first have an Alias for my API if I need to have R53 for my API GW?
Have an AWS issued certificate?
Any other resources to be defined?

Appreciate your help.
